# Regex to match everything except a group

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match, regex-negation

For a Javascript application I want to match everything in a text except some ids.

Id structure: `<#(\w|-)#>`

Input:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <#A-01#> consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et <#G-15#> dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation<#F-08#>ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure<#K-02#> dolor in reprehenderit <#S-21#> in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.

Expected match:

> ***Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,*** <#A-01#> ***consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et*** <#G-15#>***dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation*** <#F-08#> ***ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure*** <#K-02#> ***dolor in reprehenderit*** <#S-21#> ***in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.***

It looks simple but I just couldn't find a solution :(

I hope it's clear, thanks for helping!

Comment: You might try this: `/(?<=^|<#[\w-]+#>)[^<>]*(?=<#[\w-]+#>|$)/g`

Comment: @PoulBak Almost, it doesn't work if the text outside of the ids has a "<" or ">" character.

Comment: You're right, you can just use: `/(?<=^|<#[\w-]+#>).*?(?=<#[\w-]+#>|$)/g`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your initial regex in the question is false (`<#(\w|-)#>`)

---

A match is a contiguous piece of string, you can't match `AC` in `ABC` in a single match.

However, you can isolate it in multiple matches:

https://regex101.com/r/khHY8F/1

[image]

```
/((?<=<#[A-Z]-[0-9]{2}#>)|^).*?((?=<#[A-Z]-[0-9]{2}#>)|$)/gm
```

---

That said if you want the string without the tags, you don't need everything I showed and can just remove it:

```js
myString.replace(/<#[A-Z]-[0-9]{2}#>/gm, "")
```